# Finding numbers within a certain amount of the max

Tags: sql

I have a table of First, Last, Salary.

I want to find all the names of people within 25,000 of the highest salary.

I have written a nested query, but it does not seem to execute.

Any suggestions?

```
SELECT LNAME, FNAME 
FROM TABLE
WHERE in (SELECT MAX(Salary)
FROM TABLE)-25000;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT LNAME, FNAME 
FROM TABLE
WHERE Salary >= ((SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM TABLE)-25000);
```